# Illustrator - Open a PDF and keep layers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, layers, adobe-acrobat

I've created a layered PDF with java and when I tried to open it in Illustrator I figured out that Illustrator does not use these layers. They are there in Acrobat and Indesign, but Illustrator flattens all layers to one clipping path.

Is there a way to keep those PDF layers when you open it with Illustrator? Or maybe a way to convert it?

Comment: If it is merely a clipping mask in Illustrator, all the layers will be inside the clipping mask.

Comment: @Scott, thanks I'd checked that. It only has layers called `<path>` inside. The stroke and filling are on separate layers. So no named layers.

Comment: Are you seeking to retain layer **names** or merely the layers? Strokes and fills are applied to **paths** in Illustrator. They *can't* be "separate layers".

Comment: @Scott, I'm getting the feeling I'll have to look for a step before exporting the PDF. I'm generating it in Java. Opening a PDF from Indesign on the other hand, gives me the result you describe. But not from my Java exported PDF.

Comment: It sounds like the issue may be with the java library you're using - I'm not sure an extra step would help. Try researching alternate PDF libraries.